pgloader - how to specify schema
How can I specify the schema in the pgloader connection string? The following code works fine but fails when I add the last line.
I've tried various approaches, but one of the errors I encountered was "KABOOM! ESRAP-PARSE-ERROR: At".
LOAD DATABASE
     FROM mysql://<username>:<password>@localhost:3307/airflow
     INTO pgsql://<username>:<password>@localhost:5437/airflow
 
WITH include no drop, data only;

-- Set the schema search path
SET search_path TO your_schema;


I notice that in the example in the pgloader docs they send the whole lot as one command, including the LOAD, WITH and SET statements. You could try removing the semicolon after data only; to do the same.

https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/566#issuecomment-306447741

It used to be that the search_path trick was all you need here to achieve your goal, but not anymore. The way to do it in pgloader is now to use ALTER SCHEMA test_development RENAME TO public in your load command. As far as honouring the search_path setting, please run in debug mode to see the SQL statement sent for the SET environment.

https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/718#issuecomment-358435472
